# Rendering depth buffer to texture with multiple color attachments

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to write Depth buffer to a texture so that I can use it in another rendering pass. My fragment shader has multiple outputs.

```
#version 330

layout (location=0) out float weight;
layout (location=1) out float mask;

in float faceArea;
in vec2 vTexCoords;

uniform sampler2D triangleArea;

void main()
{
   weight = texture( triangleArea , vTexCoords  ).x / faceArea;

   mask = 1.0;
}
```

Following is texture and frame buffer initialization code:

```
    GL_CHECK( glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 0 ] ) ) ;
    GL_CHECK( glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_R32F , mWidth , mHeight , 0 , GL_RED , GL_FLOAT , 0 ) ); //mask

    GL_CHECK( glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 1 ] ) ) ;
    GL_CHECK( glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_R32F , mWidth , mHeight , 0 , GL_RED , GL_FLOAT , 0 ) ); //weight

    GL_CHECK( glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 2 ] ) ) ;
    GL_CHECK( glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT , mWidth , mHeight , 0 , GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT , GL_FLOAT , 0 ) ); //depth buffer
```

..........
..........

```
    GL_CHECK( glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER , mFBO[ 1 ] ) );

    GL_CHECK( glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 0 ] , 0 ) );
    GL_CHECK( glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 , GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 1 ] , 0 ) );
    GL_CHECK( glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER , GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT , GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 2 ] , 0 ) );
```

Following is final render call:

```
            GLenum buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1  };

            GL_CHECK( glDrawBuffers(2, buffers) );

            GL_CHECK( glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES , mIndices.size() , GL_UNSIGNED_INT , 0 ) ); 

            GL_CHECK( glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , mPerPixelWeightTextures[ 2 ] ) );

            GL_CHECK( glGetTexImage( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT , GL_FLOAT , mUsedPixelFlag.data ) );
            cv::Mat depthMap( mHeight , mWidth , CV_8UC1 );

        depthMap.setTo(cv::Scalar(255));

        for( int rr = 0; rr < mHeight ; rr++ )
         for( int cc = 0; cc < mWidth ; cc++ )
         {
                depthMap.at< uchar >(rr, cc) = ( 255 * mUsedPixelFlag.at< float >( rr , cc ) );

         }

        cv::imwrite( "depthmap.jpg" , mask);
```

When I access the values of texture corresponding to the depth buffer , it comes out to be 0. ( Also note that the fragment shader is fine , I have already tested the values of color attachment , and they are fine. ).

Am I making some conceptual mistake here?...I expected depth buffer to be written to GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT automatically. What is the correct way to write depth buffer to texture?

Comment: do you have the depth test enabled?

Comment: yes , I have enabled it.